# How can I get a '.mo' domain?

Tags: domain-registration, international

I represent a business in the United States. I would like to grab a '.mo' domain name, but I see some restrictions on the domain.

Is it possible to grab a '.mo' domain name without going through the hassle of registering a trademark through Macao, China? Do domain name brokers exist that will handle this cheaply and hassle-free?

Answer (score 4):

In short: [No](https://www.monic.mo/html/reg/regulation_eng.html).
Unless you think you can fake [all of this information](https://www.monic.mo/html/notice/required_doc_proof_for_domain_name_registration_eng.html). Brokers don't even come into the question; you'd need someone to set up an entire business entity or something to even get started.

Additionally, you're a bit unclear on exactly what kind of domain it is you want to get, but you should also note you can't even try to get example.mo until you lie well enough to get example.com.mo(or .org.mo, etc.)

Comment: What do you mean by **kind of domain**? I'll be happy to provide what information I can.

Comment: @stjowa I mean that you mostly likely want a second-level domain(example.mo), right? Well, you can't without first getting it's third-level version first(example.com.mo) See #5 at my "no" link above.